# Array problems (Objective C - Google Calendar API);

Tags: objective-c

Day.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GData.h"

#define KEY_CALENDAR @"calendar" 
#define KEY_EVENTS @"events"
#define KEY_TICKET @"ticket"
#define KEY_EDITABLE @"editable"

@interface Day : NSObject{
   GDataServiceGoogleCalendar * service;
}

@property (retain) NSDate* date;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* schedule;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* allWO;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* selectedWO;
@property (retain) DistanceMatrixResponse* dmr;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* array;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* data;

- (id)init:(NSDate*)d;

@end
```

Day.m

```
 @implementation Day

 @synthesize date, schedule, allWO, selectedWO, dmr, array, data;

 - (void)calendarsTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedCalendar    *)feed error:(NSError *)error{
  if( !error ){
    int count = [[feed entries] count];
    for( int i=0; i<count; i++ ){
        GDataEntryCalendar *calendar = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:i];

        // Create a dictionary containing the calendar and the ticket to fetch its events.
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [data addObject:dictionary];

        [dictionary setObject:calendar forKey:KEY_CALENDAR];
        [dictionary setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:KEY_EVENTS];

        if( [calendar ACLLink] )  // We can determine whether the calendar is under user's control by the existence of its edit link.
            [dictionary setObject:KEY_EDITABLE forKey:KEY_EDITABLE];

        NSURL *feedURL = [[calendar alternateLink] URL];
        if( feedURL ){
            GDataQueryCalendar* query = [GDataQueryCalendar calendarQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];

            NSDate *minDate = [NSDate date];  // Display Event from now
            NSDate *maxDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*90];  // ...to 90 days from now.

            [query setMinimumStartTime:[GDataDateTime dateTimeWithDate:minDate timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]];
            [query setMaximumStartTime:[GDataDateTime dateTimeWithDate:maxDate timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]];
            [query setOrderBy:@"starttime"];
            [query setIsAscendingOrder:YES];
            [query setShouldExpandRecurrentEvents:YES];

            GDataServiceTicket *ticket = [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   didFinishSelector:@selector(    eventsTicket:finishedWithEntries:error: )];
            [dictionary setObject:ticket forKey:KEY_TICKET];
        }

    }
}else
    NSLog(@"Some Error: 1");

NSLog(@"POINT 1-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= %d", [data count]);
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:data copyItems:YES];


 }

- (void)eventsTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithEntries:(GDataFeedCalendarEvent *)feed error:(NSError *)error{
if( !error ){
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    for( int section=0; section<[data count]; section++ ){
        NSMutableDictionary *nextDictionary = [data objectAtIndex:section];
        GDataServiceTicket *nextTicket = [nextDictionary objectForKey:KEY_TICKET];
        if( nextTicket==ticket ){       // We've found the calendar these events are meant for...
            dictionary = nextDictionary;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( !dictionary )
        return;     // This should never happen.  It means we couldn't find the ticket it relates to.

    int count = [[feed entries] count];

    NSMutableArray *events = [dictionary objectForKey:KEY_EVENTS];

    for( int i=0; i<count; i++ ){
        [events addObject:[[feed entries] objectAtIndex:i]];
    }


    NSURL *nextURL = [[feed nextLink] URL];
    if( nextURL ){    // There are more events in the calendar...  Fetch again.
        GDataServiceTicket *newTicket = [service fetchFeedWithURL:nextURL
                                                         delegate:self
                                                didFinishSelector:@selector( eventsTicket:finishedWithEntries:error: )];   // Right back here...
        // Update the ticket in the dictionary for the next batch.
        [dictionary setObject:newTicket forKey:KEY_TICKET];
    }
}else
    NSLog(@"Some error: 2");
//[self handleError:error];

}

- (void)refresh{

[data removeAllObjects];


GDataServiceTicket *ticket =[service fetchCalendarFeedForUsername:googleusername
                             delegate:self
                    didFinishSelector:@selector( calendarsTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:   )];


}



- (id)init:(NSDate*)d
{

self = [super init];
if(self){

    NSArray* days = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday",@"Saturday", nil];
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.date = d;
    self.allWO = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.selectedWO = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.schedule = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:self.date];
    NSInteger dayofweek = [weekdayComponents weekday];
    int st = 600;
    for(int i = 0; i<32; i++){
        int et = st +50;
        TimePeriod* tp = [[TimePeriod alloc]init:[days objectAtIndex:dayofweek-1]: st%100 == 0?st:st-20  :et%100 == 0?et:et-20];
        [schedule addObject:tp];
        st+=50;
    }

    service = [[GDataServiceGoogleCalendar alloc] init];

    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:googleusername
                                   password:googlepassword;

    [self refresh];
    NSLog(@"Count: %d", [array count]);


  }
  return self;
 }
}

@end
```

Was just wondering if someone could help!

The code above is meant to retrieve all the users googleCalendar events and calendars and store them in the "data" NSMutableArray. It does that perfectly. The google user I use has three calendars, so the count at this line

```
     NSLog(@"POINT 1-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= %d", [data count]);
```

prints 3, as it should. However at this line the count remains 0.

```
NSLog(@"Count: %d", [array count]);
```

I believe that when [self refresh] is called the code continues to run before

```
[service fetchCalendarFeedForUsername:googleusername
                             delegate:self
                    didFinishSelector:@selector( calendarsTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:   )];
```

has finished running.

All I need is to keep an array of the Days events (from Google calendar) in the day object.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, concise and representative.

Comment: 1) Add a copy of that second NSLog right after you create the `array` object.  2) Add `NSLog(@"array: %@", array.description);` right after where you currently have the second NSLog.  I'm betting that `array` will be (nil) at that point.

Comment: @outis I have added the Day.h file and my main class just initialises the object so...just Day* day = [[Day alloc]init:[NSDate date]]. However you will need to use the Google API to run the code which is not an extremely simple thing to add.

Comment: (It's not clear why you feel it's necessary to copy all of the elements in the array vs just copying their pointers.  After all, the elements in the array are dictionaries which you created and are in no danger of being shared.)

Comment: @HotLicks I did what you said and the new NSLog prints 3 and your bet it correct, the array is nil at that point. Why?

Comment: I don't really need to copy all the elements or even their pointers. I was just trying a different way because I found that the "data" array kept being empty and it was frustrating!

Comment: Probably because you're in a different instance of the class from the one where you created `array`.

Comment: Sure! That makes sense.But say I were to add         NSLog(@"data: %@", data.description); at the point after refresh is called. That just leaves me with an empty array. Is that also a result of being in a different instance of data?

Comment: @user1135469, you answered the question yourself in your question. So I don't understand the problem?

Comment: @user1135469: the extra code makes it more complete, but less concise. Part of my point was you should remove extraneous code, as explained in the linked page from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thought in the question is correct:

> I believe that when [self refresh] is called the code continues to run before
>
> `[service fetchCalendarFeedForUsername:...`
>
> has finished running.

That's exactly right. You are not setting `array` until after the asynchronous service call has returned with data, which is *after* your `init` method returns. So you're just simply reading the `array` too early.

In fact, you'll notice in your log that this line:

`NSLog(@"Count: %d", [array count]);`

is printed **before** this one:

`NSLog(@"POINT 1-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= %d", [data count]);`

Comment: Thanks! Is it too much to ask how I would go about storing the array somewhere where I can use it later?

Comment: Well, you're doing that already. It's an instance variable. But you really should use the property self.array=... to avoid a leak there if you call refresh again.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain it this way:

MyClass is declared and contains an instance variable called "theArray".

```
MyClass* instanceA = [[MyClass alloc] init]; // init leaves "theArray" nil
MyClass* instanceB = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[instanceA someMethodThatSetsTheArray];
[instanceB someMethodThatReferencesTheArray];
```

That second method call is going to find that "theArray" is nil.

Comment: Just one last thing. A which stage am I creating more than one instance of the "data" array?

Comment: You're not creating more than once instance; this is not the issue. Your initial thought was correct, pls see my explanation below. You actually answered your own question correctly.